# Placing a TextView below two ImageViews and in middle - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Please share code to achieve the layout of the screen shown in the below link. The text should be in center of the two images and all these components can be dynamic.

(https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9n2IhVep_QeNDFKaWFHVERQOVk/edit?usp=sharing)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j4bpwdmv0wgesg/Untitled%20Diagram.png

Comment: Share your link with public permission

Comment: Please try this one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j4bpwdmv0wgesg/Untitled%20Diagram.png

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />
 </LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/yourBackgroundDrawableBorder"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:background="@drawable/yourBackgroundDrawableBorder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    android:padding="xxdp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/global_menu_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Textview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to add the custom drawables for the shapes you desire for your views..and yes obviously this is a very generic way to do it. You obviously have to edit some properties or add some to suit your needs. The other way is to use LinearLayout and the `android:layout_weight="1"` property to make your imageviews similar in size.

Comment: And how to code if I want to make 3 pairs of images and similarly place text right below the pair and in center?

Comment: it would work similarly..you can give all the 3 imageviews a weight property to make sure they are all same size...and then wrap those 3 inside a linear layout ...lots of ways to do it..you will need to experiment with the properties

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="3"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```